# Does Fish shell cache the locations of previously-run commands?

Tags: fish

I know in Bash and similar shells, there is the `hash` command, which gets run when the user runs a non-builtin command, and cleared when (for example) you update `$PATH` or run `hash -r`.

And I know that the Fish shell includes the `history` command, which also gets updated when you run a command and cleared when running `history clear`.  But the purpose of the `history` command doesn't seem to be to cache paths to command files, as with Bash's `bash` command.  I'm basing this on the contents of my local `~/.local/share/fish/fish_history` file, which seems to include the commands and the timestamps they were run, but no absolute paths to command files:

```
- cmd: history
  when: 1697724735
- cmd: exit
  when: 1697724738
- cmd: history clear --help
- cmd: cat ~/.local/share/fish/fish_history
  when: 1697805134
  paths:
    - ~/.local/share/fish/fish_history
```

So my question is- does Fish have a similar command cache to Bash?

Comment: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#command-lookup doesn't mention a hash, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no command cache in fish, and so no need for a `hash` command. `$PATH` is searched for every external command.

Comment: One of the team tried it once, and at best it improved lookup by about 3%, which just wasn't worth it